# C# "Clean" way to display array (dictionary/table) to user

Tags: c#, dictionary

My problem is that I get entries from a database and want to display them. I'm looping through the rows with the help of a dictionary:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> row in database)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["column_1"]);
    Console.WriteLine(row["column_2"]);
    Console.WriteLine(row["column_3"]);
    Console.WriteLine(row["column_4"]);
}
```

I know that displaying is possible with a GUI GridViewer, but I do not want to switch to a Windows Form Application just for this purpose.

Is there a way to display this as formatted text or anything similar, that could be copied by the user if he wishes to do so?

Comment: Why not output to a file? Csv maybe?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I don't understand your question. what are you using as presentation? WPF? ASP? Console app? ... is exporting to CSV an option?

Comment: What about JSON or XML?

Comment: @Werner not sure if JSON or XML are the best option as "formatted text" for the user.. maybe XML if is to be consumed in Excel..

Comment: One easy way could be to generate a html file with a table

Comment: I'm currently using a console app. Originally my task was to just display all of it in a .txt file, which I find a little plain. I've never heard of CSV before, so I'll definitely will look into it

Comment: @GummiBoat CSV is just a text file with a separator between columns (commas or something), that can be displayed in Excel for instance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of LINQ's `Select` and `string.join` to generate a formatted string from a dictionary in a single line of code:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"a", "1"}, {"b", "2"}, {"c", "3"}};
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", x.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}\t{kvp.Value}")));
```

Result:

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/YVUV47723)

From your comment it seems like you want to display a data table, since a dictionary has only one value per key.
Here is an adaptation of my original code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("val1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("val2", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(1, 1, "a");
dt.Rows.Add(2, 20, "b");
dt.Rows.Add(3, 300, "c");
dt.Rows.Add(4, 4000, "d");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", dt.Select().Select(row => string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", row["Id"], row["val1"], row["val2"]))));
```

Note that the DataTable's `Select()` method is not the LINQ extension method, but a method that selects an array of data rows. On that array I'm using the LINQ's `Select` extension method.

Comment: Could I extend the formatting to multiple dictionary entries? I basically want to keep the standard database row-format. For my example I would need [{"Row1", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"}, {"Row2", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"}, ...]

Comment: A dictionary have only a key and value. Seems like you want to format a `DataTable`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Relying on `\t` will mean the columns will not have guaranteed alignment, right? The start of each column in each row will depend on the previous columns in that row

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes that's correct. AFAIK You can't guarantee alignment unless you know the maximum length in each of the columns in advance, or you're willing to "risk" a lot of unnecessary whitespaces between columns.

Comment: Or you're willing to truncate strings

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a DataGrid if you are using a WPF project:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding YOUR_DICTIONARY}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key_Header" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value_Header" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Sadly I'm using a console app and am not really sure how to implement this either. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: `foreach (Dictionary<string, string> row in database)
{
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in row)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

why not use `Json.NET - Newtonsoft` serialize the dictionary to a JSON, the output will be: {a:1, b:2} or [{a:1, b:2}, {c:1, d:2}] for a array

Comment: I  like the idea of converting the dictionary to a JSON, the problem is that it's not really readable unless i convert it once again to a more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

To have a bit of a "nicer" display on console (or to a file with little changes), you can try this. First get the max length for each *column* with something like:

```
var sizes = database.SelectMany(x => x)
  .GroupBy(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.Length)
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Max());
```

(I assume that `database` implements `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>`.)

Now you can display a header line:

```
foreach (var size in sizes)
{
  Console.Write(size.Key.PadLeft(size.Value));
  Console.Write(" ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

And then display each row:

```
foreach (var row in list)
{
  foreach (var column in row)
  {
    var padding = sizes[column.Key];
    Console.Write(column.Value.PadLeft(padding));
    Console.Write(" ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

`PadLeft` fills a string with spaces (or any other character when using the overload) on the *left* side, so the string is right aligned. For left alignment use `PadRight`.

Be aware, that the order of entries in a dictionary is arbitrary. So you might want to apply some specific ordering yourself.